# Best way debugging and setting breakpoints for code running inside a Kubernetes Pod?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, kubernetes-pod, vscode-debugger

I have a pod running code inside my Kubernetes cluster with many dependencies and I have found myself wanting to just setup a breakpoint and inspect different variables and state during execution. So far, I have been relying on logs to find errors, but the iteration cycles are just too slow to my liking.

Is there a way to set something up that would allow me to communicate using my IDE and debug my code with breakpoints directly inside a pod? My preferred IDE is VS Code.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a local environment?  That will be much easier to debug (you can use ordinary tools with no special setup) and to turn into a regression test.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Cloud Code for VS Code](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/debug-k8-pod).

In general debugging apps in Kubernetes is not that simple, because there are a lot of layers in between.